# how to convert string into byte array in this particular scenario

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am following the [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/details/getting-started-with-python) which was designed for Python 2x in Python 3.5. I have made updates to the code in order to make it compatible, but I am falling at the last hurdle.

In 2x Python changes between text and binary as and when, whereas Python 3x marks a clear demarcation.

I am trying to produce a CSV file for submission, but it requires that the data be in int32 format.

```
test_file = open('/Users/williamneal/Scratch/Titanic/test.csv', 'rt')
test_file_object = csv.reader(test_file)
header = test_file_object.__next__
```

Opens up a file object before making it a read object. I modified the original code, 'wb' --> 'wt' to account for the fact that by default python returns a string.

```
prediction_file = open("/Users/williamneal/Scratch/Titanic/genderbasedmodel.csv", "wt")
prediction_file_object = csv.writer(prediction_file)
```

The opens a file object before making it a writing object. Like previously I modified the mode.

```
prediction_file_object.writerow([bytearray(b"PassengerId"), bytearray(b"Survived")])
for row in test_file_object:       
    if row[3] == 'female':                                              
        prediction_file_object.writerow([row[0],int(1)])           
    else:                                   
        prediction_file_object.writerow([row[0],int(0)])    

test_file.close()
prediction_file.close()
```

I changed the writers in the for-loop into integers but as I attempt to cast the string into binary I get the following error at the point of submission:

[image: Screen shot]

I am flummoxed, I do not see how I can submit my file which needs the headers "PassengerId" and "Survivors" and also be type int32.

Any suggestions?

---

[image: screen shot showing int32 error]

Comment: `csv` files are _text_ files, not _binary_ files, i.e. `int32` doesn't make any sense.  Also, what do you think `int(1)` and `int(0)` does?

Comment: Side note: `test_file_object.__next__` should be called. Or simply do `next(test_file_object)`

Comment: Look at the bottom of the docs page (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for examples on how to open csv-files for reading/writing.

Comment: @thebjorn int(1/0) boolean values to signify whether a particular passenger on titanic survived. I also guess that the int32 error refers to the binary encodment i.e. and not int32 per say.

Comment: @Moses Koledoye New to this, why should I call it if .__next__ is equivalent?

Comment: `int(1)` is always exactly equal to `1`, and similarly for `0`.  The int32 error you're seeing is because you're not skipping the header line (you need to call `next(..)`, not just mention `.__next__`)

Comment: @thebjorn,  I understand now. Thats fixed it.